# Why does Math.floor return zero?

Tags: javascript, math

I'd like to ask why the `Math.floor` method returns zero. This is my code:

```
var duration = 217;

var sec = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60);
var min = Math.floor((duration / (60 * 1000)) % 60);
```

What's wrong there?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the modulo 60?

Comment: `duration < 1000`.

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Floor a number 0 <= x < 1 and your will get 0.

Comment: Just so you know, the `Math` library is provided by core JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: What result were you expecting?

Comment: What do you want to calculate? Maybe your formula is not doing what you are expecting. What is the unit of duration?

Comment: @halfer What does that have to do with anything.  Did the question suggest otherwise?

Comment: @ScottSauyet: yes, it did; see previous edits.

Answer (score 6):

```
var sec = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60);
```

(217 / 1000) % 60 = 0.217

The floor value of 0.217 is 0.

Answer (score 2):

The result of is `(217/ 1000) % 60` is `0.217` which `Math.floor()` rounds down to `0`.

Similarly, `(217/ (60 * 1000)) % 60` is `0.0036166666666666665` which also rounds down to `0`.

So you are seeing correct behaviour for [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), which "Returns the largest integer less than or equal to a number".